# How do I sort data in an ActiveRecord query that are returned as a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

I have this query:

```
Model.where(
  'user_id = ? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?',
  current_user.id, date1, date2
).group(:something1).count
```

which returns:

```
{257=>1, 264=>2}
```

According to the highest value I need to get:

```
{264=>2, 257=>1}
```

I can sort the data in a loop, but that's not very effective. Is there any way to get sorted data from the directly from the query? Or, is there a better way to sort the date more effectively than in a Ruby loop?

Comment: You can use [`order('something1 desc')`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering).

Comment: I think this is SQL question.

Comment: This isn't a SQL question, it's an Active Record query question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort_by` on your resulting hash, something like:

```
Model.where('user_id = ? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', current_user.id, date1, date2).group(:something1).count.sort_by { |k, v| v }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help, I've tried to use it, but I am getting the same result - data are not sorted according to the highest value.

Comment: try changing the value that's being used to sort. So, { |k, v| k }

Comment: Unfortunately still the same.

Comment: `.sort_by { |k, v| k }.reverse` is the solution. Thanks, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Using an `order_by` clause is probably the best solution. It would tell the DBM to sort the results before returning them to Ruby. If your query returned 10,000 records, `order_by` would mean you can iterate over them and they'd be in the order you need. Using `sort_by` will force Ruby to do the extra work, slowing your code needlessly. Database engines are optimized to sort results extremely quickly; It's one of the reasons we use them.

Comment: @user984621 That may not be the behaviour you expected - that seems to sort by key, which may not be what you want.